# Solve and a system of equations with a parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I've been struggling with this a bit. I've been googling in search for an answer but failed to do so.
I want to solve this system of equations with a parameter

```
Solve[
 {x == light[[1]] + (i[[1]] - light[[1]]) t,
  y == light[[2]] + (i[[2]] - light[[2]]) t,
  z == light[[3]] + (i[[3]] - light[[3]]) t,
  Z == 0},
 {x, y, z}]
```

In the end to get the answer i wanted i just got rid off variable z and used something like this

```
Solve[
  {x == light[[1]] + (1 - light[[1]]) t,
   y == light[[2]] + (2 - light[[2]]) t,
   0 == light[[3]] + (1 - light[[3]]) t},
   {x, y, t}] // N
```

But it bugs me, is there a way to get the same answer using more readable and flexible code which presents the equation in a more general way (something which looks closer to my first attempt at this Solve). And sorry if my english is weird, not my first language.

Comment: Mathematica cannot solve your first   `Solve` command, because it cann't fullfill the equation `Z==0`Perhaps itshould be `z==0`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You have 4 equations and 4 unknowns, just need to solve for all of them. Ulrich has it correct, below.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the last equation `z==0` you can solve your equations for `x,y,z,t`

```
Solve[{x == light[[1]] + (i[[1]] - light[[1]]) t, 
y == light[[2]] + (i[[2]] - light[[2]]) t, 
z == light[[3]] + (i[[3]] - light[[3]]) t, z == 0}, {x, y, z , t}]

(*{{x -> -((-i[[3]] light[[1]] + i[[1]] light[[3]])/(i[[3]] - light[[3]])), 
y -> -((-i[[3]] light[[2]] + i[[2]] light[[3]])/(i[[3]] - light[[3]])), 
z -> 0, 
t -> light[[3]]/(-i[[3]] + light[[3]])}}*)
```